# simultaneous linear congruences- Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, chinese-remainder-theorem

```
   T ≡ 126 mod 1293
   T ≡ 0 mod 3936
```

hi ive tried to solve this using the CRT existence constructive proof but `1293*207 + 3936*-68 =3` 
then i used `x = (a1*m1*n1) + (a2*m2*n2)`
and  `(0*1293*207) + (126*3936*-68)` i checked the solution and answer was wrong so im not sure what to do from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3\mid T\ $ so it's equivalent to $\ T/3\equiv 42\pmod{431};\,\ T/3\equiv 0\pmod{1312},\ $ with solution

$\ T/3 \equiv \color{}{42\cdot 1312} (1312^{-1}\bmod 431)\equiv \color{#c00}{42\cdot 1312}(-68)\equiv 211232\pmod{\ \ 431\cdot 1312}$

Scaling  the prior comgruence by $3$ yields the solution: $\ T \equiv 633696\pmod{1293\cdot 1312}$

Your mistake is that you effectively scaled *twice* by $3$ instead of once as above, i.e. you multiplied both $\,\color{#c00}{42}\,$ and $\,\color{#c00}{1312}\,$ by $3$ in your formula $\, \color{#c00}{126\cdot 3936}(-68).\,$

Comment: i dont understand what do you mean by scaled twice?

Comment: @john You have an extra factor of 3 in your answer, probably due to wrongly applying the common CRT formula  - which works only for *pairwise coprime*  moduli (so does not directly apply  to the original system). Instead we can first remove the common factor $3$ as I did above, or we can generalize the CRT formula to remove the common factor, e.g. see [this Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Generalization_to_non-coprime_moduli)